# minDate and maxDate options are not working in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker, maxdate

I'm using the "datepicker" plugin on my project, it's set to decade view, and I want to disable the future dates, for this I have used the `maxDate` option but it's not working, my code:

```js
$('#data_1 .input-group.date').datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked",
    maxDate: "0",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true
});
```

tried with `0` and `new Date`

Comment: I try in the api's web: https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ ; if you put today at End date input its generate - endDate: "today" - so try to delete maxDate and add endDate: "today"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has no `maxDate` option, you have to use [`endDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#id5).

Here a working sample:

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  todayBtn: "linked",
  endDate: new Date(),
  keyboardNavigation: false,
  forceParse: false,
  calendarWeeks: true,
  autoclose: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
var today = new Date();  
$('#data_1 .input-group.date').datepicker({
            todayBtn: "linked",
            endDate: "today",
            maxDate: today
            keyboardNavigation: false,
            forceParse: false,
            calendarWeeks: true,
            autoclose: true
        });
```

Also you can try with:

```
 maxDate: 0
```

Comment: tried your solution not working, yes i tried with both "0" and "new date()", nothing seems to be working !!

Answer (score 0):

Adding attribute  `data-date-end-date="0d"` worked for me:

```
<input type="text" id="birthDay" data-date-end-date="0d">
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are trying calendar for start date and end date then this will help you :)

```
`$("#from").datepicker({
    format : 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    endDate: '<?php echo $to; ?>',
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "startDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    format : 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    startDate: '<?php echo $from; ?>',
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "endDate", selectedDate);
    }
});`
```